# How to convert a Matrix4f to Vector3f

Tags: java, lwjgl, matrix-multiplication

I need to rotate a Vector3f in my lwjgl java game, and I do this by converting it into a Matrix4f object, then rotating it, but I need to convert it back into a Vector3f in order for it to be useful.

```
public static Vector3f transformVector(Vector3f vector, Vector3f rotation, Vector3f transformation) {
        vector = new Vector3f(vector.x * 5f, vector.y, vector.z);
        
        Matrix4f matrix = Maths.createTransformationMatrix(vector, rotation.x, rotation.y, rotation.z, 1);
        
        matrix.rotate(0, new Vector3f(1f, 0, 0), matrix, matrix);
        
        System.out.println(matrix.m01);

        System.out.println(matrix);
        
        return vector.translate(transformation.x, transformation.y, transformation.z);
    }
```

Comment: A `Vector3f` consists of three numbers. A `Matrix4f` is a 4x4 matrix and consists of 16. How do you plan to do this conversion? There's not an immediate, canonical way to do so.

Comment: I do not know exactly how matrices work, but I know that they can define a position in world space, and so I want this position, but as a vector3f.

Comment: @JamesG A humble request - we take a good amount of our time and care when writing answers. Please follow up on our efforts (not just on this question but on your other questions where relevant
), add comments if you need the answer improved or clarified, and once your issue is resolved please follow the guidelines listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to get into the implementation details of lwjgl and I'm going to focus on the math itself, because the issue is fundamentally a mathematical understanding issue, rather than one of APIs. I'm also very confused as to why you create a perfectly good transformation matrix, and then do something *other* than multiplying your position vectors by it.

**First, the tl;dr**:

- Convert your 3D vector **v** to homogeneous coordinates to obtain a 4D vector **w**.
- Perform a matrix multiplication by your transformation matrix M, to obtain a transformed (4D, homogeneous coordinates) vector **w'** = M * **w**.
- If you need non-homogeneous coordinates, convert the result back.

**and second, a nit:**

> I do not know exactly how matrices work, but I know that they can define a position in world space, and so I want this position, but as a vector3f.

No. Matrices define *linear transformations* in the linear algebra sense, not positions. When dealing with homogeneous coordinates, they also represent *affine transformations* of the coordinates involved.

**Now, an explanation of the process:**

You have a vector **v** ∈ ℝ<sup>3</sup>, representing a point in 3D space in standard coordinates.

Your transformation matrix M is 4x4, meaning that it operates on [homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates). This allows your transformation matrix to encode rotations/scalings (i.e. *linear* transforms), by placing a rotation/scaling matrix in the upper 3x3 block of the matrix:

```
a b c 0
d e f 0
g h i 0
0 0 0 1
```

This matrix can also encode a translation (i.e. an *affine* transform), by placing offset coordinates in the upper right block and an identity or rotation matrix in the subblock for the linear portion of the transformation:

```
1 0 0 a
0 1 0 b
0 0 1 c
0 0 0 1
```

**If you just wanted to know the translation contributed by your homogeneous-coordinates-transformation-matrix, you could pull it right out of that subblock.**

Recall your vector **v** ∈ ℝ<sup>3</sup> from before Suppose it's `<x y z>`. The same point can be represented in homogeneous coordinates as **w** = `<x y z 1>` ∈ ℝ<sup>4</sup>. It should be clear, by inspection of the matrix multiplication process, how the three coordinates interact with the main 3x3 subblock of the matrix, and the 1 interacts with the upper right subblock, to achieve the desired *affine* transformation (as opposed to a purely *linear* one if we didn't have homogeneous coordinates. It should also be clear that

```
[1 0 0 a]    [0]     [a]
[0 1 0 b]  * [0]  =  [b]
[0 0 1 c]    [0]     [c]
[0 0 0 1]    [1]     [1]
```

which shows that this transformation matrix definitely translates the origin by `<a,b,c>`

**Now, the important part:**

Given a transformation matrix and a vector, you can multiply them. Assuming your vector is a column vector, the multiplication of a 4x4 matrix by a 4x1 vector is well-defined, and yields a new 4x1 vector. This new 4x1 vector is the result of the transformation, also in homogeneous coordinates. As long as the last row of the transformation matrix was `[0,0,0,1]`, the new vector is of the form `<x', y', z', 1>`. It's in homogeneous coordinates, so you could go ahead and immediately multiply it by another transformation matrix (e.g. if the first was model to world space and the second was world to camera space).

On the other hand, the sub-vector `<x' ,y' ,z'>` represents the result of your transformation, if you did want it in non-homogeneous coordinates. This is the case because the fourth element was indeed 1.